# Conditional Formatting based on previous cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I'm looking to apply Conditional Formatting to a range of data I have in Excel that will display red if the most recent day of data is below what it was before, and green if it was higher.

Eg
Day,Value,  Highlight cell colour

- Day 1 1000
- Day 2 2000 Green - as it's higher than day 1
- Day 3 500  Red - as it's lower than day 2
- Day 4 6000 Green
- Day 5 4000 Red

I want to replicate this for all my data and then ideally be able to count the number of 'runs there are' eg number of red cells together so you can see the number of consecutive days that performance has fallen by.

What formula do I use to achieve both things?

Answer (score 1):

This is for Excel 2007 (hopefully you can adapt as necessary):

[image: SO17419835 example]